# how to find out what Solr version is DSE using

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to find out what Solr version our DSE setup is using. I know it uses a custom modified solr, but I want to know the index Lucene version.

Apart from opening an index with Luke, is there somewhere where DSE shows this info? I don't see it in the Solr admin overview.

EDIT: I am only counting on looking at the setup, not any doc

Answer (score 2):

Check the release notes:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/RNdse.html

You can also see it in your system.log on startup.

Note: solr and lucene versions are the same now that they are a single project:

https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/releases

Comment: I did not make myself clear apparently, I am only counting on looking at the setup,not any doc

Comment: You can also see it in your system.log on startup.

Answer (score 1):

In the solrconfig.xml, there is usually a line such as this:

```
<luceneMatchVersion>5.3.0</luceneMatchVersion>
```

This gives you the minimum version of Lucene required.

Comment: solrconfig is usually user generated. Unless they're using DSE's generateResources and it's a new core, this won't help.

Comment: Even user-generate config needs to have that line. I thought you were talking about checking an existing installation. Perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: actually looking at this value is what made me wonder what solr version were we using, as I thought it was a different one than I saw here. I was either hoping to see some value in solr admin page or some meta info in some jar, but as the jars are not similar to the ones vanilla solr has, it is not easy.

Comment: Stock Solr, has this information right in the default Dashboard page:
`lucene-impl 5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09`

Comment: I now vanilla Solr has the info in the overview page, that is why I was  looking for it there. DSE is either hiding it or the version was not shown in the version we have...

Comment: Sounds pretty desperate. Then release notes is probably the best way. Or you can look for the lucene jars within the distribution. They usually have version numbers in the name.